# Meteor Template Events

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get a hold of meteor still so there might be an easy answer to this and i'm hoping that is the case. I have this function which works and returns the correct id when my button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    var selection = (this.id);
    boardSpecs[0] = selection;
        return boardSpecs;
    });
});
```

I want to make this into a meteor click event, something like this.

```
Template.selectBoard.events({
'click button' : function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var boardType = event.target.id;
    Session.set('boardType', boardType);
    alert(boardType);
    }
});
```

This is the template where the button exists.

```
<template name = "selectBoard">
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "boardCarousel">
        {{#each boardList}}
                <div class = "span1">
                    <div class = "thumbnail">
                        <img data-src = "{{source}}" alt = "placeholder" class = "img-rounded">
                        <div class = "something">
                            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
                            <p>{{description}}</p>
                            <button type = "button" id = "{{id}}" class = "btn btn-primary">Select</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the result of `console.log(event.currentTarget.id)`?

Comment: nothing is being logged. I'm not sure what that means for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the button is part of your template, you're code is nearly right. The only different is that `this` won't point to your button, so you'll need to get it from the event:

```
Template.selectBoard.events({
'click button' : function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var boardType = event.target.id;
    Session.set('boardType', boardType);
    alert(boardType);
    }
});
```

Comment: I updated the event and I still couldn't get it to work. I added the template that the button is located.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make this easier. Your button is defined as:

```
<button type = "button" id = "{{id}}" class = "btn btn-primary">Select</button>
```

And your event handler is trying to get at the *id* of the button which is *{{id}}*.

If you use nested templates as follows:

```
<template name = "selectBoard">
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "boardCarousel">
      {{#each boardList}}
        {{> board}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="board">
  <div class = "span1">
    <div class = "thumbnail">
      <img data-src = "{{source}}" alt = "placeholder" class = "img-rounded">
      <div class = "something">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary">Select</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then *this* in your event handler will be the data context of the individual *board* and you can simply write:

```
Template.selectBoard.events({
  'click button' : function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var boardType = this.id;
    Session.set('boardType', boardType);
    alert(boardType);
  }
});
```

I'd argue that this is more *Meteoric* (to borrow an adjective from Python).
I'd also avoid using the variable name *id* because of the potential confusion with the natural MongoDB document identifier *_id*.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a body event and it worked right away. Not sure why but it did.

```
Template.body.events({
'click #selected' : function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set('board',event.target.id);
    }
});
```